# Why does Django's "request_finished" signal block the response?

Tags: python, ajax, django, signals, django-signals

If I have an ajax call from a website to a Django View, I expect it to return some response plus send a signal that the response was completed. I may use something like this (sleep is used just to demonstrate a point - this could be any long-running processes).

```
from time import sleep

@receiver(request_finished)
def comment_added(sender, **kwargs):
    sleep(5)
    return
```

The AJAX response will be blocked until the "sleep" is finished, making the user experience slow. Does that not defeat the purpose of using signals to some extent?

I know I could use Celery for this, which I'm planning to do. But I would like to understand Signals better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) not provide any async functionality.

When signal is sent, all receivers are just fired as regular function in same thread. All instructions are being executed step by step. Django will not respond to client, until all receivers will finish their work.

Django signals doesn't have anything in common with [socket singals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) for example, where you can subscribe to some event and listen to it without blocking the thread.

Example, here is a part of [django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/models/base.py#L614) of Model:

```
    meta = cls._meta
    if not meta.auto_created:
        signals.pre_save.send(sender=origin, instance=self, raw=raw, using=using,
                              update_fields=update_fields)
    with transaction.commit_on_success_unless_managed(using=using, savepoint=False):
        if not raw:
            self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)
        updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

In code `singals.pre_save.send` all receivers are executed. And until they are done, python will not continue to next line.

Most popular solution for django is [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), as you have mentioned.
Another way is to use non-blocking server framework, for example [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).

Comment: Thanks @stalk. Even if it's all on one thread, doesn't the name "request_finished" mean that it should send the response first, then deal with the signal? That would allow the UI to be fast, without requiring another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Django signals are not implemented as asynchronous callbacks as OS signals. They run in same thread one-by-one as particular phase/event is completed. All registered signals will be called within the thread which is processing a request - adding up total processing required to process that request.

So in that sense the name *signal* may mislead, but it can be still valid as signal handlers will be called when particular event is triggered (or manually sent some signal for custom signals).